# Git log --stat summary of branch

Tags: git, logging, statistics, branch, stat

I would like to show how many changes (insertions+deletions) I made on a feature branch. Is there a way to get a summary of the `git log --stat` output for the changes between 2 commits (branch root / tip).

Thanks.

Comment: Note: in addition of `git --stat`, you might be interested in the Git 2.17 (Q2 2018) feature `git --compact-summary`: see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49330686/6309).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

for a feature branch you want to use

```
git diff --stat dev..feature
```

this relies on not doing back merges. See my post here: http://dymitruk.com/blog/2012/02/05/branch-per-feature/

`--stat` can take parameters. This is useful if you have a wider terminal. You can do `--stat=200` to say that your display can accommodate 200 columns.

If you want to use this in a script, use `--numstat` instead. It will not truncate paths.

Comment: Awesome! Why did I try everything but git-diff? ;) Thanks.

Comment: This includes changes made by everyone; and `--author=` does not seem to filter the results.

Answer (score 8):

use `git diff`

```
git diff --stat <branch root> HEAD
```