# Git diff in summary?

Tags: git

With `git pull`, it shows a diff summary like this:

```
Updating 6a78751..811f788
Fast-forward
 app/Http/Controllers/SaleController.php    |   7 +-
 .../views/pages/sale/create.blade.php      | 137 +++++++++++++---
 resources/views/pages/sale/index.blade.php |   4 +-
 resources/views/pages/sale/show.blade.php  |   5 +-
 4 files changed, 123 insertions(+), 30 deletions(-)
```

Is there a way to use commands like `git diff` to get similar output?

Comment: Between what and what? Workspace and index? Index and HEAD? Two commits?

Answer (score 156, accepted):

`git log --stat` will show the amount each file was changed.

`git whatchanged` gives some detail into the files that were modified.

`git diff --stat <sha1> <sha2>` gives the files and the amount of changes between two commits.

`git diff --stat <branch>` to compare to another branch (e.g. master)

Answer (score 103):

`git diff` is indeed the command you seek.  In particular you want

```
git diff --stat
```

Other similar reports are available using

```
git diff --numstat
git diff --shortstat
git diff --dirstat
git diff --name-status
```

Answer (score 14):

> Is there a way to use commands like git diff to get similar output?

With Git 2.17 (Q2 2018), there actually is, with a result a bit more complete than `git diff -stat`:

"`git diff`" and friends learned "`--compact-summary`" that shows the
information usually given with the "`--summary`" option on the same
line as the diffstat output of the "`--stat`" option (which saves
vertical space and keeps info on a single path at the same place).

See [commit ddf88fa](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ddf88fa6166473be15822739e0a12aad4edfbbc5) (24 Feb 2018), and [commit c905cbc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c905cbc49c6455cc8d7c38c24a047396286f0fe6) (01 Feb 2018) by [Nguyễn Thái Ngọc Duy (`pclouds`)](https://github.com/pclouds).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 868f7d2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/868f7d23384931641aa4901aab27f3f23577e63b), 14 Mar 2018)</sup>

> ### `diff`: add `--compact-summary`

> Certain information is currently shown with `--summary`, but when used
> in combination with `--stat` it's a bit hard to read since info of the
> same file is in two places (`--stat` and `--summary`).
>
> On top of that, commits that add or remove files double the number of
> display lines, which could be a lot if you add or remove a lot of
> files.
>
> `--compact-summary` embeds most of `--summary` back in `--stat` in the
> little space between the file name part and the graph line, e.g. with
> [commit 0433d53](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0433d533f13671f4313c31e34707f0f5281a18e0):
>
> ```
> Documentation/merge-config.txt         |  4 +
> builtin/merge.c                        |  2 +
> ...-pull-verify-signatures.sh (new +x) | 81 ++++++++++++++
> t/t7612-merge-verify-signatures.sh     | 45 ++++++++
> 4 files changed, 132 insertions(+)
> ```
>
> It helps both condensing information and saving some text
> space.
>
> What's new in diffstat is:
>
> - A new 0644 file is shown as `(new)`
> - A new 0755 file is shown as `(new +x)`
> - A new symlink is shown as `(new +l)`
> - A deleted file is shown as `(gone)`
> - A mode change adding executable bit is shown as `(mode +x)`
> - A mode change removing it is shown as `(mode -x)`
>
> Note that `--compact-summary` does not contain all the information
> `--summary` provides. Rewrite percentage is not shown but it could be
> added later, like `R50%` or `C20%`.

---

The summary will be even more concise with Git 2.29 (Q4 2020), since "[`git diff --stat -w`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b58e47a929ec3d3d5fe63f18ae9539ffe9051c51/Documentation/diff-options.txt#L128)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---statltwidthgtltname-widthgtltcountgt))</sup> showed 0-line changes for paths whose changes were only whitespaces, which was not intuitive.

> Such paths are now omitted from the stat output.

See [commit 1cf3d5d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1cf3d5db9bd11514465d3692216211315f0dc82c) (20 Aug 2020) by [Matthew Rogers (`ROGERSM94`)](https://github.com/ROGERSM94).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit b58e47a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b58e47a929ec3d3d5fe63f18ae9539ffe9051c51), 03 Sep 2020)</sup>

> ### [`diff`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1cf3d5db9bd11514465d3692216211315f0dc82c): teach `--stat` to ignore uninteresting modifications
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Matthew Rogers</sup>

> When options such as `--ignore-space-change` are in use, files with modifications can have no interesting textual changes worth showing.
> In such cases, "[`git diff --stat`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/1cf3d5db9bd11514465d3692216211315f0dc82c/Documentation/diff-options.txt#L123)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---statltwidthgt,ltname-widthgt,ltcountgt))</sup> shows 0 lines of additions and deletions.
> Teach "`git diff --stat`" not to show such a path in its output, which would be more natural.
>
> However, we don't want to prevent the display  of all files that have 0 effective diffs since they could be the result of a rename, permission change, or other similar operation that may still be of interest so we special case additions and deletions as they are always interesting.

Comment: I just started reading the answer and I knew, this must be researched by @vonc ;)

Comment: @Timo Researched yes, but merely reporting of the awesome work from Nguyễn Thái Ngọc Duy  and Matthew Rogers: they are doing the actual work.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a command that I find my self going to often that shows me the details for just the last commit:

`git diff --stat HEAD~`

it produces this output like this for the last commit:

```
$ git diff --stat HEAD~
 blazelib/BlazeDefs.cpp                             |  16 +++--
 blazelib/BlazeDefs.hpp                             |   1 -
 ui/code.qrc                                        |   1 +
 ui/cpp/Business.cpp                                |   5 ++
 ui/cpp/Business.hpp                                |   7 ++
 ui/qml/components/BlazeSummaryCell.qml             |  22 +++---
 ui/qml/components/BlazeSummaryDetails.qml          |  95 +++++++++++++++++++++++++
 ui/qml/components/ConfirmEndProcedurePopup.qml     | 432 +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 ui/qml/components/MagpieConfirmParametersPopup.qml |  24 +------
 ui/qml/main.qml                                    |  10 ++-
 ui/qml/shui/TitleMlText.qml                        |   3 +-
 11 files changed, 287 insertions(+), 329 deletions(-)
```