# How I can get line of code for each commit

Tags: git, logging, gitlab

4 Weeks ago, i typed "git log" in my project. and the result is :

```
commit 587b621b90ca3ba2332d252c04d3957028cbc6bc
Author: Agus Priyono <aguspriyono2012@gmail.com>
Date:   Fri Sep 28 07:56:44 2018 +0700

fixing middleware of status

 app/Http/Kernel.php                          |  3 ++-
 app/Http/Middleware/InvoiceMiddleware.php    |  3 ---
 app/Http/Middleware/MatchingMiddleware.php   |  3 ++-
 app/Http/Middleware/SeeProfileMiddleware.php | 24         ++++++++++++++++++++++++
 resources/views/admin/set-matching.blade.php |  1 -
 routes/user.php                              | 18 +++++++++---------
 6 files changed, 37 insertions(+), 15 deletions(-)

commit f997564af36a8bf700c37b298b54e6e07dd491a4
Author: Agus Priyono <aguspriyono2012@gmail.com>
Date:   Fri Sep 28 07:29:01 2018 +0700

fixing update status

 app/Http/Controllers/Admin/CheckStatusController.php |  3 ++-
 resources/views/admin/set-matching.blade.php         | 14 +++++++-------
 2 files changed, 9 insertions(+), 8 deletions(-)
```

but now, when i type "git log", the result don't have line of code (insertions and deletions )  like this :

```
commit 80c0b0c4c4100649cd5dec6df16206f63fc27f7e
Author: Dwi Yulianto <trafalgarlaw.dwi@gmail.com>
Date:   Fri Nov 2 10:55:11 2018 +0700

update again

commit f39df6add36d91373ba13b29039a5d576d7554d8
Author: Dwi Yulianto <trafalgarlaw.dwi@gmail.com>
Date:   Fri Nov 2 10:31:11 2018 +0700

update tody

commit 4bd1372236982c0e0db8921c8d96dae2dd3ef677
Author: Dwi Yulianto <trafalgarlaw.dwi@gmail.com>
Date:   Wed Oct 31 16:10:16 2018 +0700

add blank
```

how I can get the line of code for each commit?
thank you.

Comment: I think you deleted, renamed, or changed your .gitconfig file, because Git does not change its output format by itself. Check your `~/.gitconfig` file.

Answer (score 1):

Try first:

```
git log --compact-summary
```

That should give you back the type of log format you were seeing.

[`git log --compact-summary`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---compact-summary):

> Output a condensed summary of extended header information such as file creations or deletions ("new" or "gone", optionally "`+l`" if it’s a symlink) and mode changes ("+x" or "-x" for adding or removing executable bit respectively) in diffstat.
>   The information is put between the filename part and the graph part.
>   Implies `--stat`.

Note that it [is fairly recent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49330686/6309): Git 2.17+ (Q2 2018).
So check your Git version.

As commented, `git log --stat` is similar (and older)

Comment: `git log --stat` may get you similar result.

Comment: @josephting Yes, yhat is why I mention "implies --stat"

Comment: Great, Thank you @VonC for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try git diff. Much cleaner and elegant way of getting the same information:

```
HarshMacBookPro:TitanAdserver harshprateek$ git diff
diff --git a/app.py b/app.py
index 2a93c2f..742ba79 100755
--- a/app.py
+++ b/app.py
@@ -52,6 +52,8 @@ class User(db.Model):
     username = db.Column(db.String(32), index=True)
     password_hash = db.Column(db.String(64))
     role = db.Column(db.String(32))
+    address = db.Column(db.String(128))
+    country = db.Column(db.String(128))

     def hash_password(self, password):
         self.password_hash = pwd_context.encrypt(password)
@@ -119,6 +121,11 @@ def addFeed():
     status = routes.addFeedToDB(request)
     return status

+@app.route('/api/v1/createPublisherFeed')
+def createPublisherFeed():
+    status = routes.createPublisherFeed(request)
+    return status
+
 @app.route('/api/v1/users/<int:id>')
 def get_user(id):
     user = User.query.get(id)
@@ -304,7 +311,7 @@ def addPublisher():
 @app.route('/viewPublishers')
 #@login_required
 def viewPublishers():
-    json_feeds = mongo_db.feeds.find()
+    json_feeds = mongo_db.publisher_details.find()
     return render_template('viewpublishers.html',feeds=json_feeds)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please try to answer the question instead: `diff` does not show the number of modified lines, but the changes themselves.

Comment: 'how I can get the line of code for each commit? thank you.'

Isn't he looking for lines instead of number of lines???

Comment: Look at the command outputs in the question before/after the "bug".